# Why is $\epsilon^{p,q}(X):=\Gamma(X,\bigwedge^p\Omega^1_X\otimes\overline{\bigwedge^p\Omega^1_X})$?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, complex-geometry, exterior-algebra

Here $\Omega^1_X=(T^*X)^{1,0}$, from : [this notes](http://people.bath.ac.uk/ac886/pubs/hodge.pdf) we have

$\epsilon^{p,q}(X):=\Gamma(X,\bigwedge^p\Omega^1_X\otimes\overline{\bigwedge^p\Omega^1_X})$

But I wonder why it's tensor not wedge? Shouldn't it be $\epsilon^{p,q}(X):=\Gamma(X,\bigwedge^p\Omega^1_X\wedge\overline{\bigwedge^p\Omega^1_X})$?

See O'well's book (p.33) or [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_differential_form)

Comment: You mean $\overline{\bigwedge^q\Omega^1_X}$ everywhere, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us reduce ourselves to the fiber. If $V$ and $\bar V$ are two **different** $\Bbb R$-spaces with $W=V\oplus \bar V$, and assume there is an isomorphism over $\Bbb R$, $v\to\bar v$, between the two summands.

We fix a basis $B$ of $V$. Thus also one, $\bar B$, for $\bar V$.

Now let us consider an element in $$\wedge^\cdot W\ .$$ It can be written uniquely "adapted" w.r.t. the basis $B\sqcup \bar B$ of $W$ over $\Bbb R$. Adapted means the following. We order $B$ and correspondingly $\bar B$. Each wedge product in $\wedge^\cdot V$ is rewritten so that we have first a wedge in $\wedge^\cdot V$, and then one in $\wedge^\cdot \bar V$.
This gives a well defined map
$$ \wedge^\cdot W\to \wedge^\cdot V\otimes \wedge^\cdot \bar V\ ,$$
which is inverse to the obvious map
$$ \wedge^\cdot W\leftarrow \wedge^\cdot V\otimes \wedge^\cdot \bar V\ ,$$
in opposite direction.

So why $X\otimes Y$ and not $X\wedge Y$ for $X=\wedge^\cdot V$, $Y=\wedge^\cdot \bar V$?

Because these are (seen as) **different** spaces from the start. (And there is no alternation in general, for two different spaces, $X,Y$. There is a space $X\otimes Y$, and a space $Y\otimes X$, defined using universal constructions, but there is no $X\wedge Y$. We would have to identify the two tensor products in a common world, but in our case we definitively not want to identify, for instance $dz_k$ with $d\bar z_k$ in the tangential space, we did our best to have them different.)

Comment: Thanks, but if so then any element of $\epsilon^{p,q}(X)$ would be in the form of $\sum_{|I|=p,|J|=q}dz^I\otimes d\bar{z}^J$, but on O'well's book, an element of $\epsilon^{p,q}(X)$ would be in the form of $\sum_{|I|=p,|J|=q}dz^I\wedge d\bar{z}^J$.

Comment: In case we write the wedge, we see the element inside $\bigwedge^\cdot W$. A matter of notation. I thought the question was about the isomorphism $$\wedge^\cdot W\cong \wedge^\cdot V\otimes \wedge^\cdot \bar V\ .$$ To be strict, we should use the inclusions $I=I_V$ and $\bar I=I_{\bar V}$ into $W$ to know in which space we write the elements. Then the element $(v_1\wedge\dots\wedge v_p)\otimes (\bar v_1\wedge\dots \wedge\bar v_q)$ goes to $$Iv_1\wedge\dots\wedge Iv_p\ \boxed{\wedge}\ \bar I\bar v_1\wedge\dots \wedge \bar I \bar v_q\ .$$And here the wedge makes sense!

Comment: One more question, can I say $W$ is just $\bigwedge^p\Omega^1_X)\bigwedge(\overline{\bigwedge^p\Omega^1_X})$?

Comment: Yes, this is possible. I think most people use this last notation ("for less confusion"). I did a lot of computations using a $wedge$ between $dz^I$ and $d\bar z^J$ for multiindices $I,J$ of "degrees" $p,q$. A writing like $dz^I\otimes d\bar z^J$ would be possible, but then this element would be considered in $\wedge ^pV\otimes \wedge^q\bar V$, so it is not directly possible to add this $(p,q)$-form with one in bidegree $(p+1,q-1)$, say. In this case, we have to map them in the same space, which is  $\bigwedge^{p+q}W$. Writing $dz^I\wedge d\bar z^J$ would be a clear sign we work in last space.